# QGIS display map on a certain lat/lon range

Tags: qgis

I really want to make a screen capture of New York city (have min_lat, min_lon, max_lat, max_lon). Later I will use that picture as background and plot other information in python. Is there a way to let QGIS display the certain range?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

In the map composer, select your map box and then go to the item properties panel.

In here you can set min/max X and Y to define the extent shown.

Comment: where is item properties panel?

Comment: When you open the map composer there should be a panel which contains a few sub panels. From memory one of these is page settings, another is atlas settings then one called item properties

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to save the currently extents displayed as a georeferenced image (Project > Save as image...)